# Backbone.Marionette Template Loading Asynchronously

Tags: backbone.js, jquery-templates, marionette, backbone-events, backbone-views

We are using Backbone and Backbone.Marionette for our project. We are currently storing all of the templates for our views on the server, and we've overwritten the loadTemplate call to load them asynchronously.

However, when we use a layout view, since the template for the view is loaded asynchronously, it seems like we cannot access the layout's regions immediately. The following is an example:

```
var layoutView = new Layout();
var itemView = new ItemView();

App.containerRegion.show(layoutView);
layoutView.mainRegion.show(itemView); <---- This is where the issue would occur.
```

If we don't load template from the server asynchronously, then it would work fine. What would be a good way to implement this? We want to keep templates on the server, instead of loading everything at once. We also want to avoid binding to the render event of the layout view all over our code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to override the render function of Marionette.ItemView, where you first load the template data and render the view on successfully load the template:

```
  render: function(){          
    if (this.beforeRender){ this.beforeRender(); }

    this.trigger("before:render", this);
    this.trigger("item:before:render", this);

    var data = this.serializeData();
    var templateSrc = this.getTemplate();

    $.ajax({
      url: 'templatesFolder/' + templateSrc,
      success: _bind(function(template){
         var html = Marionette.Renderer.render(template, data);
         this.$el.html(html);

         if (this.onRender){ this.onRender(); }
         this.trigger("render", this);
         this.trigger("item:rendered", this);
      }, this)
    })

    return this;
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to grab the [Marionette.Async](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette.async) plugin. It was built to do exactly what you want.

But, you need to know that there are performance implications with grabbing templates from a server, async. The network latency for doing this can cause users to think the application is unresponsive if you don't have something on the screen telling them that the app is working behind the scenes (like as spinner graphic).

It would be best to grab as many templates as you can all at once, to cut down on network latency and transfer. There's [a blog post that a friend of my wrote](http://johndavidmathis.wordpress.com/2012/09/13/preloading-backbone-marionette-templates-2/) on doing exactly this.